# xUnit testing Azure Functions w/ .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to figure out a way to design xUnit tests for my Azure Functions, which are based on [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker-preview) example.

As you can see, with .net 5 functions, you are expected to start `func host start` in your functions' project directory, then you can fire functions and debug.

Here's the program.cs of the functions project

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
           .ConfigureAppConfiguration(c =>
           {                   
               c.AddCommandLine(args);
           })
           .ConfigureFunctionsWorker((c, b) =>
           {
               b.UseMiddleware<FunctionExceptionMiddleware>(); //an extension method of mine to register middlewares...
               b.UseFunctionExecutionMiddleware();
           })
           .ConfigureServices(s =>
           {
               //add other services here,
               
               CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("");
               BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("");

               s.AddScoped(r => storageAccount);
               s.AddScoped(r => blobServiceClient);

           })
           .Build();
```

As you can see, I register different types for DI to work properly, and I also register a middleware, to handle unhandled exceptions, so testing only the function's class `Run` method isn't optimal, because they rely on DI and also I need the middleware(s) to be tested as well.

Here an example function

```
[FunctionName("GetAsset")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req, FunctionExecutionContext executionContext)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseData(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    
    var container = req.GetQueryStringParam("container"); //extension method to retrieve query parameters...
    var blob = req.GetQueryStringParam("blob");


    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(container) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(blob))
    {
        executionContext.Logger.LogInformation($"GetAsset function - missing arguments in request string");
        return new BadRequestObjectResult("");
    }


    return new OkObjectResult("Success");
}
```

As far as I can see, to get optimal tests, `func.exe` from the toolkit would need to be launched, then with an `HttpClient` I could make requests to `http://localhost:7071/api/MyFunction`.

I've thought of launching `func.exe` through `Process.Start()` before each of the tests, but it's kind of hackish as I don't really know when it is ready (func.exe compiles all assemblies before showing a "Worker process started and initialized" message) and tests could give false fails because of that.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'd avoid testing the functions this way and relying on the Host. If you design the functions correctly you can just test them independently as normal classes (or, have them pass through to objects you can test) and mock the dependencies or use a ServiceCollection/Provider to resolve the function objects

Comment: Also, don't use CloudStorageAccount, it's old. BlobService client might be too depending on which lib you reference. The newer azure storage sdks actually have built in methods for registering queue/blob clients in DI. I'd strongly suggest using that, it works with net5 functions as well

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 `HttpRequestData` is not really mockable it seems. I have logic that retrieves query string parameters from its `Url` property and it is read only - can't set it from the xunit test.

Comment: I have some azure functions somewhere that includes testing of the httprequest, but that was for 3.x... If I get some time I'll see if I can locate them and their tests. It had to be done in a roundabout way if I recall, but it was possible